# Unexpected token on line 29

Tags: javascript, html, unexpected-token

My friends and I are trying to make a website from scratch and we have barely ever touched html. We have got a private domain, but we just started and don't seem to know how to define this unexpected token found on line 29. Any help would be well appreciated. This is the only thing limiting us to run our code (I think).

`<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>`

This is what pops up whenever trying to run the code:

[image: This is what pops up whenever trying to run the code.]

Picture of code on line 29:

[image: Picture of code on line 29]

[line 28-44](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ktKb.png)

Comment: How do you _run_ the code?

Comment: What type of file are you attempting to create? is it a *.html?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the images given (more would be nice, or code samples), I can see the function `signOut()` being called, but I can't see a `{` after it. Inside your `<script>` tags, the function call should be `function signOut(){    //Your code     }`. Please see if it works.

In addition to this, I'd check that all tags are ended (for example `<script>` should have a matching `</script>` tag after the necessary JS). As others have said, as well, make sure the file ends with .html!